# How to add textbox dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript, clone

Help with this criteria ?

Users can be able to add as many Names as they want, ADD NAME link serves the purpose for this.

How can I handle this specification ? 
Please check the spec below:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this goes well.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addfieldset() {
        var namefieldset = document.getElementById("name").cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById("names").appendChild( namefieldset );
    }
    function deletefieldset( e ) {
        var namefieldset = e.parentNode;
        namefieldset.parentNode.removeChild( namefieldset );
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="names"><div id="name">Name: <input name="namefield" type="text"/><a href="#" onclick="deletefieldset( this )">delete</a></div></div>
    <input id="addnamebtn" type="button" value="Add Name" onclick="addfieldset()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I remembered an excellent post from "quirkmodes" briefly explained this. I still hold in my bookmarks. Here it [is](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html).

Good Day!

Comment: Thanx Ramiz, completed the work according to the spec and easy too
quirksmode.org helped me a lot to solve this spec...thanx to all who gave a helpfull support

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = $('#input').clone().attr('name', 'name2').attr('id', 'input-2').appendTo('body')
```

You can go further and clone the entire row/div with `$(el).clone()` and then do `.find('input')` and modify the name and id attribute values so they're unique and don't conflict. You can pass `true` to clone if you want to copy the event handlers.

Incomplete non-jQuery "solution" since I don't know *exactly* at which point the OP is in since he claims he can clone nodes now..

```
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="foo">
      <label for="first_name">name:</label><input type="text" name="first_name[]  " id="first_name"><a href="#">delete</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="add">add name</a>
  </div>
  <script>
  (function() {
    var add = document.getElementById('add'), counter = 0;
    add.onclick = function() {
      var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('div'), last = false;
      if ( rows.length ) {
        for ( var i = rows.length; i--; ) {
            if ( last ) { break; }
            if ( rows[i].className.length && ( ' ' + rows[i].className + ' ' ).indexOf(' foo ') != -1 ) {
              last = rows[i];
            }
        }
      }
      if ( last ) {
        var newNode = last.cloneNode(true), wrap = document.getElementById('wrap'), input = newNode.getElementsByTagName('input');
        input.id = input.id + (counter++);
        wrap.appendChild( newNode );
      }
    }
  })();
```

Comment: it's not a complete solution, but a good start. it looks like you'll want to tie that to the "click" event of the "Add name" text... and you'll have to use some sort of counting variable for the name attribute... better would be just to have it as an array "name[]" and not bother modifying it at all.

Comment: I never intended to post a full solution without seeing his specific markup, and I'm perfectly aware of what's possible.

Comment: Perhaps a little remaker: the solution by Meder uses jQuery, i don't see that mentioned anywhere.

Comment: i can clone the name txtfield, i'm able to add as many as i can and delete the respective txtfiled....the problem is...how can i get values ?

<input type="text" id="work_2_name" name="work[2][name]" />
<input type="text" id="work_3_name" name="work[3][name]" />

how can i get values entered in this textbox

Comment: @ Meder, when i click on the submit, how can i get value entered in work[2][name] txtfield ? may be this seems very idiotic, but i'm not able to solve it meder, please help me

Comment: You should know that you will *not* get a proper solution until you provide some code.

Comment: can i have ur mail, not able to post the code in correct order